# PHP mail linebreaks

Tags: php, email, line-breaks

I have a php mail script that works just fine as long as I define the body text in a var like this:

```
$body = "Some text goes here\n\nSome other text goes here!";
```

When done like this the linebreaks "\n" works perfect in the mail.

Now I want to insert the body text in a config file from which the mail script retrieve the text. So I do a constant in the config file like this:

```
define('_body_', 'Some text goes here\n\nSome other text goes here!');
```

And my mail script will now look like this:

```
$body = _body_;
```

But now the linebreaks is not "shown" in the mail. Instead the mail looks like this:

"Some text goes here\n\nSome other text goes here!"

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Use double quotes (`"`) instead of single ones (`'`)

Comment: I'm amazed that people downvote a post because those less experienced don't know as much as them. Remarkable really. We all started somewhere.

Comment: Thanks nickhar. What is known and relatively simple to some people is at the same time new territory for others. Isn't that exactly what keeps Stackoverflow and others like it alive??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` will be translated to a line break if it is inside double quotation marks (as in your first example) but not inside single quotation marks (as in your second example).

Answer (score 5):

It's because you are using single quotes `'`.

Try

```
define('_body_', "Some text goes here\n\nSome other text goes here!");
```

Comment: Humprey: thanks! Feeling kind of stupid :)

Comment: No worries, easy mistake to make at first!

Answer (score 3):

Make your define with double quotes:

```
define('_body_', "Some text goes here\n\nSome other text goes here!");
```